# how to split data of two object from one JSON response?

Tags: android, json, servlets, gson

from server i'm getting json response...but it contais data of two objects..one is of ArrayList Type and 2nd is one POJO(HomeVO) class. i want to split data and store into different objects. i am usnig GSON api.

```
Servlet:

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(questions));
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(homeVo));


 Json Response:

[{"questionId":2,"question":"Quality","typeOfQuestion":2},    {"questionId":3,"question":"Satisfaction","typeOfQuestion":1},{"questionId":4,"question":"overall","typeOfQuestion":2}]{"feedbackName":"IMS","expiryDate":"2014-12-12","createdDate":"2014-10-24","feedbackId":2}



Android Parsing:



HttpClient httpClient = WebServiceUtils.getHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());

            data = gson.fromJson(reader, arrayListType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("json array",
                    "While getting server response server generate error. ");
        }
```

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: You should better change your servlet side first. You are not returning a valid json. You are concatenating two jsons side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:
1. Manually parse the strings (What is not recommended)
2. Convert the JSon objects into objects using Gson and then convert it back into one json object also using Gson.

Let me know, if you need more detailed info

More expl.:

Lets say u have two different JSon string, called  JsonA and JSonB.
in order to join them, you have to download the Gson library

```
class AClass{
int idA;
String nameA;
} // Note that the variable's names must be the same as the identifiers in JSON

class BClass{
int idB;
String nameB;
}
class JoinedClass{
BClass bClass;
AClass aClass; //don't forget getters and setters
}
public String joinJson(String JsonA , String JsonB){
Gson gson = new Gson();
AClass aClass = new AClass();
BClass bClass = new BClass();

aClass = gson.fromJson(JsonA, AClass.class);
bClass = gson.fromJson(JsonB, BClass.class);
JoinedClass joinedClass = new JoinedClass();
joinedClass.setAClass(aClass );
joinedClass.setBClass(bClass);
return gson.toJson(joinedClass);
}
// but you know, just after writing this code, i found that there might be an easier way to do this. 
// Thanks for attention!
```

Comment: yeah please elaborate ur ans...thnx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two POJO classes for Questions and HomeVO. Then follow these steps:

You can create another DTO with two lists (questions and homeVo).

```js
public class ResultDTO {

  private List < HomeVO > homeVoList;
  private List < Question > questionList;

  //use your getters and setters here: 

}
```

now, use those setters to set your values like you have already done.

then pass that object (ResultDTO) to your gson:

```js
//assuming the ResultDTO object name is resultDto...

response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(resultDto));
```

now if you check the result in client side, you may have a json response like below:

```js
[questionList: [{
   "questionId": 2,
   "question": "Quality",
   "typeOfQuestion": 2
}, {...}, ],
homeVoList: [{
   "feedbackName": "IMS",
   "expiryDate": "2014-12-12",
   "createdDate": "2014-10-24",
   "feedbackId": 2
}, {..}]
```

so you can get your json objects in response divided like this (this is for web, I dont know how you access it):

```js
//assuming the json reponse is 'data':
var homeVoList = data.homeVoList;
var questionList = data.questionList;
```

try and see... just a guidance...haven't try actually..